# How to pass one Event handler to another event handler in c#

Tags: eventhandler

I have one software which show the 4 camera view. Its working fine. I want to modify it.

Now the problem is I want to capture the picture from 4 different camera view. the software only capture the 4 camera view unless i click on one of them view during this selection click event is being called and it will pass that particular camera event handler and store that handler data to array. once i get the camera panel handler I can click on the camera image capture button to take the snapshot.

But I want to pass the event camera handler (which tell me which screen is being selected for screenshot) to the capture button event..

So how is it possible? Does any one have idea. Copying the two event handler code below.

This API capture the snapshot from camera screen that is selected by `private void realPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

```cs
private void CapturePicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (m_curRealPanel.m_playhandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        return;
    }
    String strTemp = string.Copy(LocalSetting.m_strPicSavePath);
    DateTime oDate = DateTime.Now;
    String strCurTime = oDate.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    LocalSetting.m_strPicSavePath += m_deviceInfoList[m_curRealPanel.m_deviceIndex].m_ip;
    LocalSetting.m_strPicSavePath += "_";
    LocalSetting.m_strPicSavePath += (m_curRealPanel.m_channelIndex + 1);
    LocalSetting.m_strPicSavePath += "_";
    LocalSetting.m_strPicSavePath += strCurTime;

    byte[] picSavePath;
    GetUTF8Buffer(LocalSetting.m_strPicSavePath, NETDEVSDK.NETDEV_LEN_260, out picSavePath);
    int iRet = NETDEVSDK.NETDEV_CapturePicture(m_curRealPanel.m_playhandle, picSavePath, (int)NETDEV_PICTURE_FORMAT_E.NETDEV_PICTURE_JPG);
    if (NETDEVSDK.FALSE == iRet)
    {
        showFailLogInfo(m_deviceInfoList[m_curSelectedTreeDeviceIndex].m_ip + " chl:" + (m_curSelectedTreeChannelIndex + 1), "CapturePicture", NETDEVSDK.NETDEV_GetLastError());
        //return;
    }

    showSuccessLogInfo(m_deviceInfoList[m_curSelectedTreeDeviceIndex].m_ip + " chl:" + (m_curSelectedTreeChannelIndex + 1), "CapturePicture");

    LocalSetting.m_strPicSavePath = strTemp;
}

private void realPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_curRealPanel = sender as PlayPanel;
    setDeviceTreeSelectNode();

    if (true == m_curRealPanel.m_recordStatus)
    {
        LocalRecodBtn.Text = "Stop";
    }
    else
    {
        LocalRecodBtn.Text = "Record";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do - can you reword your second paragraph?

Comment: "the software only capture the 4 camera view unless i click on one of them view during this selection click event is being called and it will pass that particular camera event handler and store that handler data to array" is **[gobbledygook](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gobbledygook)** .

Comment: Could you please show the full code? Not just the handlers.

Comment: It seems that when you do a `realPanel.Click` that you set `m_curRealPanel` in the handler so that when you do a `CapturePicture.Click` you can refer to the `m_curRealPanel` there. I'm unsure what the problem is.

Comment: Hello Guys, Its working now.. I have create TimerThread which call at every 50 seconds and it pass through event handler and pass the handler..